# Calling HTTP Node server inside HTTPS instance, SSL error

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, ssl, https

I'm trying to connect to a socket.io inside a Node server from a React client.

Both, the React client and the instance that the Node server is located (it's a microservice, there's also a Java container running there, both within a separated docker container) have https protocols. React client is inside a s3 bucket.

The thing is, Node server is HTTP only, has no certificate, and it's causing the request to the socket.io to fail.

The connection happens without any trouble inside de develop EC2, which is not HTTPS, also running normally with localhost.

Cors are enabled.

Is there a way, without having to turn Node serve into HTTPS, to make this requests not return SSL erros?

If not, what is the easiest way to turn it into a HTTPS server to run along with the Java server?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you use nginx or apache reverse proxy?

Answer (score 1):

A very short answer. Try using nginx as WebSocket proxy for you socket.io server.

Here are couple links:

- [nginx as WebSocket proxy](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/)
- [SSL configuration to make it an https](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/terminating-ssl-http/)
- [Socket.io official configuration](https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/#NginX-configuration)

Comment: I ended up using a SSL certification for the server, turned into https.

Tried the Nginx way but didn't work out...

Comment: its alright. as per best practice, node servers are more performant if not dealing with ssl termination. its just additional performance boost. but your way should be good too :)